# LWC Button with parameterized Apex method

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, aura, dynamic

I want an LWC Button component where the user putting it on a Flexipage can define which Apex method to call? By putting the name of a Callable class into a parameter field?

**Is that possible in LWC?**

Comment: I think you are asking if the identity of a wire or imperative Apex method can be dynamically generated in an LWC. I'm not aware of this being possible, but a solution is to import and use a single "routing" Apex method, for this the LWC, which takes three parameters: 1. FQN of the Apex class to instantiate, 2. The callable "method name" and 3. The callable parameters.

Comment: Phil W's suggestion is sensible, but GIANT SECURITY KLAXON. Salesforce implemented class-level security for LWC calling Apex for a reason, and this could bypass that mechanism. It could let a user with access to the button controller execute arbitrary Callable classes

Comment: @Aidan that is true, though is the case for anything that uses "reflection" to instantiate something. That said, it is still limited to those that the user has access to and that they know about... Indeed, from what I can see, Callable is all about standardizing code access within and across namespace boundaries. (Personally, I think it is really horrid since you lose all compile time support, and would have been far happier to have see enhanced reflection capabilities in Apex instead.)

Comment: @PhilW I used your solution. Make it a real answer and I can accept it. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking if the identity of a wire or imperative Apex method can be dynamically generated in an LWC. I'm not aware of this being possible, but a possible solution is to import and use a single "routing" Apex method. The method needs to take three parameters:

1. FQN of the Apex class to instantiate,
2. The callable "method name" and
3. The callable parameters (an arbitrary JavaScript object that will get deserialized to the required `Map<String, Object>`).

This aura enabled method's job is to instantiate the target Apex class, as a [Callable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_System_Callable.htm), and invoke `call` with the "method name" (the "action" parameter) and the callable parameters.

Obviously, the named Apex class must:

- Implement the `Callable` interface.
- Be instantiable in the context of the code that does the instantiation. E.g. if you package this LWC and its aura enabled method, and the Apex class is outside that package, the class must be declared `global` to make it visible within the package.

There may be a minor concern over security of this service, but I think it fair to say that the Callable must be specifically exposed to allow its use and that the entire reason this interface exists is to provide a "portable API" across package boundaries.